# A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}'

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, clean-architecture, rx-java3

I want to call  api  using rxjava3 inside getCampaigns function in CampaignRepositoryImpl.kt class but I am getting following error [image: error] A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')

below  CampaignRepositoryImpl.kt class

```
import de.westwing.campaignbrowser.domain.Campaign
import de.westwing.campaignbrowser.domain.CampaignRepository
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single

class CampaignRepositoryImpl(private val apiInterface: ApiInterface) : CampaignRepository {

    override fun getCampaigns(): Single<List<Campaign>> {

       apiInterface.getCampaigns()

    }

}
```

below my interface class I am getting API call

```
interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("cms/test/campaigns.json")
    fun getCampaigns(): Single<CampaignsResponse>

}
```

below CampaignRepository

interface CampaignRepository {

```
fun getCampaigns(): Single<List<Campaign>>
```

}

below my CompaignResponse.kt

```
data class CampaignsResponse(val metadata: CampaignsMetadata)
```

below CampaingsMetadata

```
data class CampaignsMetadata(val data: List<CampaignDto>)
```

below

```
data class Campaign(val name: String, val description: String)
```

below CampaignDto

```
class CampaignDto(val name: String, val description: String, val image: ImageDto)
```

I want to know where I am making mistake what I have to do in order to avoid error

Comment: Err, you need to return something from the function? `return apiInterface.getCampaigns()`

Comment: even I  am returning I am getting the same error

Comment: @broot I am doing as exactly as you told but I am getting following error Type mismatch.
Required:
Single<List<Campaign>>
Found:
Single<CampaignsResponse>

Comment: Yes, but this error message is also quite descriptive. Your `ApiInterface.getCampaigns()` returns  `Single<CampaignsResponse>`, but you need to return `Single<List<Campaign>>` from outer function, so you need to convert first to the second one. I guess `CampaignResponse` contains `List<Campaign>` somewhere inside.

Comment: @broot can you explain your answer with coding sample

Comment: @broot I have tried both answer it did not work even I have added additional code

Comment: Answer of Ben P. is really good. It is not easy to provide you a fully working example, because we can't know how to convert `CampaignsResponse` to `List<Campaign>`. This is your code, your data structures and only you can know how to do this. You can provide the definition of `CampaignsResponse` and `Campaign`. Hopefully, `List<Campaign>` is somewhere inside `CampaignsResponse` and then it will be easy. If not then it really depends on your specific data structures.

Comment: I have added fullcoding structure and I have added my response

Comment: @broot what additional classes do you need

Comment: As I said: `CampaignsResponse` and `Campaign` classes. Your problem is really on how to convert the first to the second. We can't know this if we don't even know what is `CampaignsResponse` and `Campaign`.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, you provided `CampaignsResponse`. But again, there is only some `CampaignsMetadata` object inside. We don't know what it is.

Comment: Ahh, we are almost there, `CampaignDto` please... :-D

Comment: @broot added d))

Comment: Well, something didn't work, the code is missing.

Comment: @broot I want to know what is missing

Comment: @broot  let me know if you need more classes

Comment: I mean you just added "below CampaignDto", but there is no `CampaignDto`  below.  For your information, I don't ask for all these classes to annoy you. We really need to use all of them here ;-)

Comment: @broot sorry I have added my mistake d))

Comment: Ok, I think now we have everything. Take Ben P. answer and replace `it.campaigns` with: `it.metadata.data.map { Campaign(it.name, it.description) }`. I believe (but only believe) that it should at least compile.

Comment: @broot thank you so much it  is working tack a mycket it means thank you in swedish

Comment: I'm glad it worked. But I think you really need to understand what your own code does and try to work with it by yourself. As you can see, it is not that easy to provide a fully working example remotely, it requires knowing half of your existing codebase. Converting one class to another with almost the same fields is pretty much basics.

Comment: okay I will do as you toldme

Comment: @broot can you check mu other question as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your api interface, we can see that the type of `getCampaigns()` is `Single<CampaignsResponse>`. In your repository implementation, on the other hand, the type of `getCampaigns()` is `Single<List<Campaign>>`.

Since both are `Single<Foo>`, you'll need to `map` from one to the other.

Given your class implementations, this should work:

```
override fun getCampaigns(): Single<List<Campaign>> {
   return apiInterface.getCampaigns().map { response ->
       response.metadata.data.map {
           Campaign(it.name, it.description)
       }
   }
}
```

This `map` call is taking a `CampaignResponse` and turning it into a `List<Campaign>`.

Comment: can you check my updated code I am getting following error

Comment: Your screenshot shows an `entity` package with `CampaignResponse` and `CampaignMetadata`, as well as a `domain` package with `Campaign`. We'd need to see the contents of those files to provide any more details.

Comment: I have added CampaignResponse and CampaignMetadata, as well as a domain package with Campaign

Comment: @BenP. Please replace `it.campaigns` in your answer with: `it.metadata.data.map { Campaign(it.name, it.description) }` - just for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Since your ApiInterface returns Single, you can just return it in method body.
You might have to check out that CampaignRepository has getCampaigns() method and it should return Single.

```
    class CampaignRepositoryImpl(private val apiInterface: ApiInterface) : CampaignRepository {
    
        override fun getCampaigns(): Single<CampaignsResponse> {
    
           return apiInterface.getCampaigns()
    
        }
    
    }
```